# Multiple kafka topics with different hdfs outputs using logstash not working

Tags: apache-kafka, logstash

I used logstash to consume kafka data and save log to hdfs, and I would like split hdfs output with different kafka topics, my logstash configuration is as following:

```
input {
  kafka {
    bootstrap_servers => "192.168.1.14:9092"
    group_id => "logstash_act"
    topics => ["act", "log"]
    decorate_events => true
    consumer_threads => 5
    }
}
output {
    if [kafka][topic] == "act" {
        webhdfs {
            host => "192.168.1.8"
            port => 50070
            user => "root"
            path => "/ubuntu/input/logstash-%{+YYYY}-%{+MM}-%{+dd}.act"
            codec => plain { format => "%{message}" }
            idle_flush_time => 10
            retry_interval => 0.5 flush_size => 500
        }
    }

    else if [kafka][topic] == "log" {
        webhdfs {
            host => "192.168.1.8"
            port => 50070
            user => "root"
            path => "/ubuntu/input/logstash-%{+YYYY}-%{+MM}-%{+dd}.log"
            codec => plain { format => "%{message}" }
            idle_flush_time => 10
            retry_interval => 0.5 flush_size => 500
        }
    }
}
```

There is no errors, but just there are no output at all.

Comment: Well, are you sending more than the flush size or waiting longer than the flush time? Does the `/ubuntu/input`  directory even exist on HDFS? And have you tried adding the stdout debug output in your logstash config to test this pipeline?

Comment: I solve the problem, [kafka][topic] should be [@metadata][kafka][topic]

Comment: Feel free to put that as an answer below rather than leaving it as a comment